# Android NDK: break point installation failed when adding break points

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I'm using android NDK and when I add break point to my cpp file with ctrl+shift+B, a yellow warning occurs that shows:

```
Breakpoint attribute problem: installation failed
```

And the break point has no effect. How to add breakpoints properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting eclipse, this warning is gone. I don't know how many times I have to restart eclipse a day.